# IG graph API: video views on a carousel

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get the insights of a video carousel that has a video.

When I call `GET /{ig-media-id}/insights` I can access the `video_views` metric but the numbers are strange because it is always higher than my reach and also higher than impressions.

I get the same result calling the metric `carousel_album_video_views`.

How does IG calculate this metric on carousels? I couldn't find this information anywhere. Is that a sum, an average, or what?

My guess is that it is a sum of the views of each child element.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights/) the `reach` metric indicate the **unique** Instagram accounts that has saw the carousel content, so that you can have a higher value of `video_views` because it could have been seen multiple times.

Moreover the documentation say that you cannot get the insights for the videos inside a carousel, so I think that the `carousel_album_video_views` is just a sum of `video_views` for each media.

Comment: ```video_views``` on video items indicate unique views, if you watch a video two times it doesn't count. It seems like ```carousel_album_video_views``` is something else